# Remove the semicolon at the end of the line (algorithm2e)

Tags: algorithm2e

When using the algorithm2e package each line MUST end with \;. In the compiled document a semicolon also appears at the end of the line. One can avoid this if the line is written inside a macro. The classical example is:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\; 
\While{not at end of this document}{read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
```

I was wondering whether is possible to have the semicolon removed from the compiled document. Is there some package option or a simple macro that can do this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is stated in the document that every line should end with `\;` indeed. 
That being said, you can use `\DontPrintSemicolon` to remove the `;` in the output, however it seems that using `\\` also works, without creating much difference. I guess this is related to some parameters hidden in `\;`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\; 
\While{not at end of this document}{read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\DontPrintSemicolon
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\; 
\While{not at end of this document}{read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\\ 
\While{not at end of this document}{read current\\
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\\
current section becomes this one\\
}{
go back to the beginning of current section
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```